# How to specify replace url option in router link angular html template

Tags: html, angular

```
 <button color="dark" fill="outline"  [routerLink]="['/home']" size="medium"
          >Click here to add some</button>
```

how should I pass replace URL option just like we do in the TS file

```
 await this.router.navigate(['/profile'], { replaceUrl: true });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it myself by seeing type file of angular routing :) here is how I do it

```
<button color="dark" fill="outline" replaceUrl="true"   routerLink="['/home']" size="medium"
              >Click here to add some</button>
```

Comment: I tried this, but I just get an error saying type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. Any insight as to what's going on there?

Comment: fixed now its because of useless binding @PaulBunion

Comment: This still gives me the error described above

Answer (score 0):

```
<button replaceUrl="true" routerLink="/home">Click here to add some</button>
```

You dont have to use [] for replaceUrl and routerLink if those are not bound but simple values.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is correct, but now in Angular you also need to bind those properties, even for booleans, like this:

```
<button [replaceUrl]="true" [routerLink]="['/home']">Click here to add some</button>
```